# Ho does Jersey Resource config package scanner work

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have something like this

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyJaxRSApplication extends ResourceConfig {


    public MyJaxRSApplication() {
        String[] packages = {"com.xxx.xyz.rules.rest"};
        packages(packages);
}
}
```

I do have a security service to intercept request

```
package com.xxx.xyz.rules.restfilter;

@Priority(20)
@Provider
public class UrlBasedAuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

}
```

Above code snippet is working, but I can't get my hear-around understanding how jersey scanning works. Does it takes as "com.xxx.xyz.rules.rest*".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but if what you are showing works, then it looks like a bug (rather than a feature) to me. How it's documented to work is to scan the exact package specified, and all its subpackages, recursively

```
com.xxx.xyz.rules.rest
com.xxx.xyz.rules.rest.sub1
com.xxx.xyz.rules.rest.sub1.sub2
com.xxx.xyz.rules.rest.sub1.sub2.tillstackoverflow
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet Not sure how this is working but I'm currently on Jersy 2.5.1, I tried to make sure to rule out all the other cases if there is some registration but none found